# Объединить метки [распознавание-речи] и [speech-recognition]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить [распознавание-речи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8) и [speech-recognition](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/speech-recognition), основная - [распознавание-речи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8). На данный момент по 30 вопросов по обеим меткам, описания нет ни в одной, ни в другой. Оставить предлагаю русскоязычный вариант.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я помню, пришли к решению, что русскоязычные метки предпочитаем.

Синонимизировал и объединил.